# Take picture from Bootmenu (grub2)

Tags: boot, grub2

Is there a possible way of taking a picture of my bootmenu ?
example : http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:xOLNRxyhahN-FM:http://i3.photobucket.com/albums/y71/Cocasoca/grub2.jpg&t=1

( note : cellphone pictures are excluded -> i have a low pixel cellphone cam :( )

Comment: It would be difficult, is a (half decent) digital camera out of the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot the disk from under VirtualBox. You'll need to do this from another installation (or perhaps Live -- otherwise the disk won't be available for VirtualBox to control) and you just add the disk (you *can* add real disks) as the primary drive.

Anyway, once you're in, VirtualBox will let you take a screenshot.

Otherwise you could use a video-out (s-video or composite, whatever, if anything, your computer supports) and another computer with a video capture card. You can use VGA if you have [a VGA capture card](http://www.vgacapture.com/) but most people don't. Then just capture all the video output from the first computer on the second. Bit of a task if you ask me but it's worth it for serious video recording.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason he wants to take a picture of grub is that he has some problem or error message he wants to record. If he uses virtualbox it will be a different setup and this problem may not occur.

Comment: I don't agree with your analysis. When people say they want a picture of their boot menu, I hear they want a picture of their boot menu, not errors that show up afterwards (which, I agree would likely not show). Grub is going to look exactly the same on bare metal or virtualised.

Comment: Or at least to show what's coming up to help diagnose an error: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10503/boot-takes-a-lot-of-time

Comment: thank you for the ideas .. especially the video-out thing is something i didn't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer gives you some options for low-level video/image capture.

But I've noticed you started another thread on a particular issue you get following grub. If you're just trying to tell us grub's available options, the contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` will do.