# How can I see what happens during the boot process?

Tags: boot, configuration, grub2

On my machine booting takes more than a minute which is annoying when I see that Windows 7 boots in 20 seconds.

Here is what I get when the machine is booting.

[image: Picture of screen]

How can I see what happens when booting up?

Comment: Have you got proprietary drivers installed? That could explain the lack of a graphical boot. It doesn't explain the slowness.

Comment: Jup, i have proprietary drivers installed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Open Grub by holding <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> on boot
- Edit the top option by pressing <kbd>e</kbd>
- Search the boot command until you see the two words "quiet splash".
- Delete these from that line and press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.

This will show you what's happening behind the scenes (and what it's getting stuck on).

This is temporary. It will revert to the old behaviour on the next boot so it's *fairly* safe.

If you want to make it permanent, edit `/etc/default/grub` as root, delete "quiet splash" from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable, save and then run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Just to complete: at Natty, you should remove "vt.handoff=7" also.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use a program called Bootchart (click to install: [bootchart](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/bootchart) and [pybootchartgui](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pybootchartgui)) to plot a diagram of everything that's happening while booting. It will point out where most time is spent and whether there is anything seriously wrong.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20061019182936/http://www.bootchart.org/images/bootchart.debian.mcrae.0.png) is what a typical bootchart looks like.

[image]

Comment: Link has gone bad :( Here's a fresh one: http://www.bootchart.org/images/bootchart.debian.mcrae.0.png

Comment: Nowadays (23.04), use `systemd-bootchart -o bootchart.svg` instead.