# Why does my system boot so slowly?

Tags: 10.10, startup, shutdown, reboot

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 a few days ago. It is really awesome but the problem is that it takes unusually long time (about 20 minutes) for the login screen to appear after the Ubuntu startup screen. This only happens if I shutdown the computer. There is no problem when I restart the computer.

Comment: Is it any problem with hard disk having some bad sector? Usually disk checking might take a long time. Try reinstalling Ubuntu ,if it still fails may be you have to format and reinstall.

Comment: You can follow the two answers in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10503/boot-takes-a-lot-of-time) to get us more information.

Comment: I suspect improper `unmount` at shutdown and a long `fsck` at boot.

Comment: @shellholic not unless he chose to use ext2 when he installed; ext3 and ext4 ( the default ) are journaled and so they avoid the need for a fsck after an unclean shutdown.

Comment: @psusi: personal note for later. It's obvious, that a computer that boot in 20 minutes and reboot rapidly has an ext3/4 format.

Comment: @shellholic: how do you figure that?

Comment: @psusi: sarcasm.

Comment: Try pressing Escape or Space during the startup graphic; you should be able to actually see the Linux kernel messages as it starts up.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to solve this problem is with [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/). It will let you see
which process in the boot up sequence is slowing things down.

> sudo apt-get install bootchart pybootchartgui

Once it is installed just start the gui at the command line with

> pybootchartgui

You have to have at least rebooted once for this to work.

My guess would be that you disks were being check with [fsck](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/fsck.8.html) which happens periodically.

[image: bootchart]

Comment: that is one groooovy conky you have got going on there!