# Ubuntu is taking way longer to load on faster computer than on slower computer. Help?

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, usb

I've recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 on an old computer I'm now using for a server. It worked great, and is much faster than Windows, so I decided to dual boot it on my computer that I actually use. Because my video card is Nvidia and has Optimus software on it, and refused to work at every solution I could find, it took me a while to get it working properly. As soon as I got it working, I noticed that my computer was taking longer to boot up to the login screen than it was taking on the server computer.

My current computer is a Dell Inspiron 17r special edition laptop, which has 8gb gddr3 ram, 8 cores of roughly 3 Ghz processor, a Nvidia GeForce GT 650M Graphics card... You get the point. It's got the power, but It's just taking longer. The server computer however, has only 4 gigs of ram, and a dual core 3 ghz processor, and integrated graphics.

Also, they're both running on Linux Ubuntu 12.04.2 64 bit.  I'll let you decide which is supposed to be faster... Server computer boots to login screen in well under 20 seconds. Main computer takes well over the time to login on the server one and pull up Mozilla, and start the server.

The output of `dmesg` is available here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5977206/

Comment: It may help to mention that I recently installed Gnome on accident, but I've gotten rid of it, I think.  The boot splash background is back to normal, and it no longer shows up on the login screen.

Comment: Please post the contents of /var/log/boot but I suspect you may be having problems mountinmg some partition

Comment: Please see the following question and add a bootchart to your question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/29627/why-does-my-system-boot-so-slowly

Comment: @user183466 also, boot without the USB webcam drive attached, see if that makes any difference. Add to the `lsblk`, since I suspect you have the Ubuntu partition to the very end of the drive.

Comment: It can't find the command sudo /var/log/boot, and i don't know how to boot without the webcam driver.   I also don't see how the boot thing will help oli.