# why does Ubuntu boot so slowly? (13.04)

Tags: boot, 13.04

I wonder if anyone has any idea why my system boots so slowly. It's taking 40 seconds to reach the login screen, another 20 or so to display the desktop, and another minute or so  before my main software (Firefox and LibreOffice Writer) are ready to go.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 (the secure remix), dual booting with Win8 (which actually boots a lot snappier, frustratingly).

My last bootlog .png is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17718002/david-laptop-raring-20130730-4.png)

I've done a fair bit of googling, but none of the suggestions I've come across have helped. (I did find one useful bit of info [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/205163), which displays ALL the start-up applications in 'Startup Applications', not just a couple of them. But even after unchecking all but the essentials (and the unknowns) I'm still booting slowly.

Any advice would be really appreciated. Let me know if any more info would be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your boot log, it looks like fsck is taking about 10 seconds to check your disks for errors.  That shouldn't happen on every boot, so it's an obvious place to start looking for problems.  In particular, it's taking time checking a vfat drive.

Try booting to rescue mode and check your disks for errors from there. There are certain filesystem problems that need to be resolved interactively.

If you are mounting windows drives, check them for errors from windows.