# Ubuntu 14.4 is booting so slow even with 8gb of ram and i5 4g cpu

Tags: 14.04

I have got Lenovo g50 70 with i5 4g CPU and 8GB of ram, I have got ubuntu 14.4 installed in it, but even with this kind of configuration but system boots so slow.
The output from `dmesg` command:

```
[    0.629895] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    0.632494] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[    0.632512] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x11142120
[    0.632513] intel_idle: v0.4 model 0x45
[    0.632514] intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
[    0.632641] ipmi message handler version 39.2
[    1.588656] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2394.457 MHz
[    2.589535] Switched to clocksource tsc
[   16.260957] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for AC is loaded, please  retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[   16.261604] ACPI: AC Adapter [ADP0] (off-line)
[   16.261722] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[   16.261753] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[   16.261781] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
[   16.261784] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[   16.261808] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
[   16.261810] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[   16.262048] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[   16.262229] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[   16.266235] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[   16.267190] brd: module loaded
[   16.267705] loop: module loaded
[   16.267983] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[   16.268052] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[   16.268053] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky 
[   16.268086] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[   16.268117] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[   16.268121] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[   16.268231] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[   16.268236] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[   16.268248] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[   16.272157] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[   16.272174] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io mem 0xd071c000
[   16.280497] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[   16.280541] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[   16.280543] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   16.280545] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[   16.280546] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-63-generic ehci_hcd
[   16.280548] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[   16.280653] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   16.280659] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[   16.280757] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[   16.280764] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[   16.280765] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[   16.280772] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[   16.280777] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[   16.280884] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[   16.280888] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[   16.280962] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[   16.280983] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X
[   16.281031] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[   16.281033] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   16.281034] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   16.281035] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-63-generic xhci_hcd
[   16.281037] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[   16.281207] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   16.281219] hub 2-0:1.0: 9 ports detected
[   16.283172] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[   16.283176] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[   16.283205] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[   16.283207] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   16.283209] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   16.283210] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-63-generic xhci_hcd
[   16.283212] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[   16.283381] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   16.283390] hub 3-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[   16.288674] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[   16.302459] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[   16.302465] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[   16.302579] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[   16.303063] rtc_cmos 00:04: RTC can wake from S4
[   16.303178] rtc_cmos 00:04: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[   16.303206] rtc_cmos 00:04: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[   16.303267] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[   16.303319] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.27.0-ioctl (2013-10-30) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[   16.303328] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[   16.303418] TCP: cubic registered
[   16.303504] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[   16.303656] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[   16.303665] Key type dns_resolver registered
[   16.303846] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[   16.304764] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: e253281fe265ee3ceafcaa3f292e212b95f0359a'
[   16.304775] registered taskstats version 1
[   16.306762] Key type trusted registered
[   16.309763] Key type encrypted registered
[   16.309768] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[   16.309770] IMA: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[   16.310078] regulator-dummy: disabling
[   16.310117]   Magic number: 15:654:668
[   16.310195] rtc_cmos 00:04: setting system clock to 2015-09-13 05:40:12 UTC (1442122812)
[   16.310848] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[   16.310849] EDD information not available.
[   16.310876] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[   16.312879] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[   16.345342] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[   16.345349] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[   16.346042] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1336K (ffffffff81d20000 - ffffffff81e6e000)
[   16.346043] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
[   16.347587] Freeing unused kernel memory: 784K (ffff88000173c000 - ffff880001800000)
[   16.348802] Freeing unused kernel memory: 680K (ffff880001b56000 - ffff880001c00000)
[   16.358258] systemd-udevd[126]: starting version 204
[   16.373532] psmouse: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   16.377230] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[   16.377370] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[   16.377375] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: irq 62 for MSI/MSI-X
[   16.377377] r8169 0000:01:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   16.377400] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: SSS flag set, parallel bus scan disabled
[   16.384941] r8169 0000:01:00.0: irq 63 for MSI/MSI-X
[   16.385117] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g at 0xffffc90010e70000, 68:f7:28:8c:3b:32, XID 10900880 IRQ 63
[   16.385121] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   16.392566] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[   16.392570] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq stag pm led clo only pio slum part sxs deso sadm sds apst 
[   16.392988] scsi0 : ahci
[   16.393057] scsi1 : ahci
[   16.393109] scsi2 : ahci
[   16.393161] scsi3 : ahci
[   16.393197] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xd071b000 port 0xd071b100 irq 62
[   16.393200] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xd071b000 port 0xd071b180 irq 62
[   16.393202] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xd071b000 port 0xd071b200 irq 62
[   16.393204] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xd071b000 port 0xd071b280 irq 62
[   16.592760] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[   16.712863] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[   16.719074] ata1.00: ATA-8: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB, 2BA30001, max UDMA/100
[   16.719077] ata1.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[   16.725223] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[   16.725230] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[   16.725298] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[   16.725392] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST1000LM024 HN-M 2BA3 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   16.725510] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[   16.725537] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[   16.725540] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[   16.725545] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   16.725564] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   16.725566] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[   16.725577] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   16.725584] hub 1-1:1.0: 8 ports detected
[   16.893003] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   16.909383] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0129
[   16.909386] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   16.909388] usb 2-4: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[   16.909389] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[   16.909390] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 20100201396000000
[   16.989601] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x594f03)
[   17.004332] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x70, 0x15, 0x0a.
[   17.021113] usb 2-6: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   17.045134] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[   17.049064] ata2.00: ATAPI: MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8FBS, F801, max UDMA/100

[   17.051598] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[   17.058100] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8FBS   F801 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   17.063666] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[   17.063669] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[   17.063790] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[   17.063841] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[   17.088965] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
[   17.107778] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=6513
[   17.107781] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[   17.107783] usb 2-6: Product: Lenovo EasyCamera
[   17.107784] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: J5PECP0T3
[   17.111200]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 
[   17.111832] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   17.281324] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   17.298611] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc
[   17.298615] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[   17.381402] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   17.701658] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[   18.048123] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
[   18.064455] XFS (sda1): Mounting Filesystem
[   18.518189] XFS (sda1): Ending clean mount
[   18.958163] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   50.264146] Adding 7811068k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:7811068k FS
[   50.337074] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   50.473977] systemd-udevd[313]: starting version 204
[   50.649431] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   50.653604] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   50.726239] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   50.740101] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[   50.740105] checking generic (c0000000 410000) vs hw (c0000000 10000000)
[   50.740107] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
[   50.740124] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[   50.742793] input: Ideapad extra buttons as /devices/platform/VPC2004:00/input/input6
[   50.796380] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   50.796401] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   50.796403] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   50.796409] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   50.796411] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   50.796415] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   50.799357] rts5139: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   50.801480] scsi4 : SCSI emulation for RTS5139 USB card reader
[   50.801592] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- xD/SD/M.S.       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[   50.801776] usbcore: registered new interface driver rts5139
[   50.801966] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   50.803234] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   50.808852] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Lenovo EasyCamera (0c45:6513)
[   50.824416] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 64 for MSI/MSI-X
[   50.824427] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   50.824429] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   50.824519] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[   50.841295] input: Lenovo EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/input/input7
[   50.841351] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   50.841352] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   50.866440] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   50.906377] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   52.501734] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[   52.505099] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   52.505102] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[   52.559637] type=1400 audit(1442122848.717:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=509 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   52.559642] type=1400 audit(1442122848.717:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=509 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   52.559645] type=1400 audit(1442122848.717:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=509 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   52.559939] type=1400 audit(1442122848.717:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=509 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   52.559942] type=1400 audit(1442122848.717:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=509 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   52.560096] type=1400 audit(1442122848.717:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=509 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   52.717582] XFS (sda3): Mounting Filesystem
[   52.717603] XFS (sda3): Log size 1424 blocks too small, minimum size is 1596 blocks
[   52.717605] XFS (sda3): Log size out of supported range. Continuing onwards, but if log hangs are
[   52.717605] experienced then please report this message in the bug report.
[   52.830149] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[   53.072019] XFS (sda3): Ending clean mount
[   53.226941] XFS (sda2): Mounting Filesystem
[   53.257370] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   53.258744] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   53.270400] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710010002030d00
[   53.289185] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   53.289194] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20131115/psargs-359)
[   53.289199] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PEGP.DD02._BCL] (Node ffff8802439142d0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20131115/psparse-536)
[   53.289271] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:23/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8
[   53.290564] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   53.290917] acpi device:48: registered as cooling_device5
[   53.290989] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input9
[   53.291052] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[   53.291391] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 65 for MSI/MSI-X
[   53.294178] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   53.294427] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   53.294432] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   53.294436] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000830-0x000000000000083f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPRL 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   53.294439] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000830-0x000000000000083f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPR_ 2 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   53.294442] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   53.294443] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000800-0x000000000000082f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPRL 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   53.294446] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000800-0x000000000000082f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPR_ 2 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   53.294448] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000800-0x000000000000082f SystemIO conflicts with Region \IO_D 3 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   53.294451] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   53.294452] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   53.294607] HDA driver get symbol successfully from i915 module
[   53.294718] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 66 for MSI/MSI-X
[   53.302397] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 67 for MSI/MSI-X
[   53.303127] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   53.307566] hda_codec: CX20751/2: BIOS auto-probing.
[   53.307793] autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   53.307795]    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   53.307797]    hp_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   53.307798]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   53.307799]    inputs:
[   53.307801]      Internal Mic=0x1a
[   53.307802]      Mic=0x19
[   53.308466] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel 
[   53.308468] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
[   53.308481] hda_codec: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[   53.309381] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:
[   53.309384] Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation
[   53.309647] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 68 for MSI/MSI-X
[   53.312058] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input11
[   53.312122] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input10
[   53.315600] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input14
[   53.315671] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input13
[   53.315718] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input12
[   53.318892] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[   53.318896] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   53.329946] [fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 7650 MBytes.
[   53.330068] [fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 666f revision: 0 count: 1
[   53.330253] [fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0x3000, size: 0x100
[   53.330260] pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[   53.330414] [fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   53.330434] [fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 15.20.2 [Feb 27 2015] with 1 minors
[   53.510887] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   53.521355] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   53.521428] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   53.521671] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   53.594158] XFS (sda2): Ending clean mount
[   53.637963] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   53.739363] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
[   53.768806] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   53.768808] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   53.768810] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   53.768811] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   53.768812] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   53.768813] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   53.768814] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   53.874864] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[   54.364752] init: failsafe main process (730) killed by TERM signal
[   54.771297] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   54.771301] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   54.771309] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   54.776317] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   54.776328] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   54.776333] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   54.797306] type=1400 audit(1442122850.953:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=858 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   54.797312] type=1400 audit(1442122850.953:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=858 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   54.797575] type=1400 audit(1442122850.953:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=858 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   55.313152] init: cups main process (863) killed by HUP signal
[   55.313159] init: cups main process ended, respawning
[   55.771293] type=1400 audit(1442122851.925:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=948 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   55.794475] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
[   55.794520] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   55.794749] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   55.795761] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   55.796005] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   55.808323] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   55.808538] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   56.735740] /dev/vmmon[1137]: Module vmmon: registered with major=10 minor=165
[   56.735745] /dev/vmmon[1137]: Module vmmon: initialized
[   56.744697] Guest personality initialized and is inactive
[   56.744739] VMCI host device registered (name=vmci, major=10, minor=56)
[   56.744740] Initialized host personality
[   56.759323] NET: Registered protocol family 40
[   58.268012] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1240 (vmnet-netifup)
[   58.268019] /dev/vmnet: hub 1 does not exist, allocating memory.
[   58.268030] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 1 successfully opened
[   58.884266] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1250 (vmnet-dhcpd)
[   58.884275] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 1 successfully opened
[   58.960102] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1255 (vmnet-natd)
[   58.960108] /dev/vmnet: hub 8 does not exist, allocating memory.
[   58.960118] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
[   59.113962] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1256 (vmnet-netifup)
[   59.113970] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
[   59.339665] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1272 (vmnet-dhcpd)
[   59.339676] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
[   59.480912] wlan0: authenticate with c4:e9:84:6b:dd:aa
[   59.483421] wlan0: send auth to c4:e9:84:6b:dd:aa (try 1/3)
[   59.485677] wlan0: authenticated
[   59.487369] wlan0: associate with c4:e9:84:6b:dd:aa (try 1/3)
[   59.491484] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c4:e9:84:6b:dd:aa (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[   59.493968] wlan0: associated
[   59.493987] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   59.586850] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1228 (vmnet-bridge)
[   59.586858] /dev/vmnet: hub 0 does not exist, allocating memory.
[   59.586868] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 0 successfully opened
[   59.586875] bridge-wlan0: device is wireless, enabling SMAC
[   59.586876] bridge-wlan0: up
[   59.586984] bridge-wlan0: attached
[   59.786925] userif-2: sent link down event.
[   59.786929] userif-2: sent link up event.
[   61.319341] userif-2: sent link down event.
[   61.319345] userif-2: sent link up event.
[   61.689103] deprecated_sysctl_warning: 150 callbacks suppressed
[   61.689106] warning: process `vmware-hostd' used the deprecated sysctl system call with 1.1.
[   62.839249] userif-2: sent link down event.
[   62.839253] userif-2: sent link up event.
[   65.340296] fglrx_pci 0000:03:00.0: irq 69 for MSI/MSI-X
[   65.340955] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 2878
[   65.341079] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 2879
[   65.341205] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 2880
[   65.341321] [fglrx] IRQ 69 Enabled
[   65.352360] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[   65.352362] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f7b4000, size:4000 
[   65.352363] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f7b8000, size:548000 
[   65.352364] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:7ffee000, size:12000 
[   65.398351] [fglrx] IRQ 69 Disabled
[   65.399188] [fglrx] module unloaded - fglrx 15.20.2 [Feb 27 2015]
[   65.402715] AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel 
[   65.402718] AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
[   65.412637] [fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 7650 MBytes.
[   65.412751] [fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 666f revision: 0 count: 1
[   65.412947] [fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0x3000, size: 0x100
[   65.413070] [fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   65.413084] [fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 15.20.2 [Feb 27 2015] with 1 minors
[   66.378181] fglrx_pci 0000:03:00.0: irq 69 for MSI/MSI-X
[   66.378921] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 2904
[   66.379062] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 2905
[   66.379172] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 2906
[   66.379289] [fglrx] IRQ 69 Enabled
[   66.389630] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[   66.389632] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f7b4000, size:4000 
[   66.389632] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f7b8000, size:548000 
[   66.389634] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:7ffee000, size:12000 
[   66.410193] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   68.665919] [fglrx] IRQ 69 Disabled
[   68.718059] [fglrx] module unloaded - fglrx 15.20.2 [Feb 27 2015]
[   68.719585] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   68.803584] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   68.808115] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (2995) terminated with status 1
[   68.808126] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   69.423741] init: anacron main process (1077) killed by TERM signal
[   84.901334] type=1400 audit(1442122881.033:62): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=4407 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   84.901339] type=1400 audit(1442122881.033:63): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=4407 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   84.901601] type=1400 audit(1442122881.033:64): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=4407 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  300.061692] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[  919.746035] init: irqbalance main process (1084) killed by TERM signal
[ 2600.745870] systemd-hostnamed[9753]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[ 3636.980526] systemd-hostnamed[5791]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

Please help..

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Edit your question with the output of `dmesg` in terminal.

Comment: please refer [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/115797/6-ways-to-speed-up-ubuntu/) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35497/how-to-fix-very-slow-ubuntu-booting)

Comment: just posted the output from the dmesg comamnd, please check and help

Comment: "ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for AC is loaded, please  retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared" Oh and this is NOT an Ubuntu related problem but a kernel related problem ( reference https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1013535 ) Happens on suse and gentoo too... unsupported or not 100% supported hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can visualise your boot sequence by installing these packages, and **reading their `man` pages**.

```
$ apt-cache search bootchart
bootchart - boot sequence auditing
pybootchartgui - boot sequence visualisation
```