# bootchart disappeared after installation?

Tags: bootchart

I looked through this thread [How to fix very slow Ubuntu booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35497/how-to-fix-very-slow-ubuntu-booting) about bootchart. I installed the bootchart via terminal but I failed to find it. Tried to type it in a search bar but bootchart wouldn't come up. Can I launch it from terminal ?

Btw I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, my machine is powered by processor AMD quad core 2.2 GHz and armed with 8 GB of RAM.

Whilst booting I'm getting disturbing messages on the screen. I do ultimately reach fully loaded system but as a Ubuntu lover I don't like those messages I'm getting. Obviously there's something wrong going on.

Thanks for any feedback !

Comment: You don't need any separate `bootchart` application on 16.04 any more, as there is one integrated in `systemd` already which is used since Ubuntu 15.04. Simply boot your computer normally, then after it's completely finished, open a terminal and start playing around with the `systemd-analyze` command. Its most useful arguments are probably `time` to get a short boot time info, `blame` to order the boot processes by execution time and you can also run `systemd-analyze plot > my-bootchart.svg` to create a graphical boot chart and save it under the specified filename as SVG.

Comment: Used all the commands you mentioned. I'm thankful I learned some useful commands. Sadly it didn't tell me anything about those failed processes. Will keep looking for solution. Thanks for your time !

Comment: I tweaked the grub with e4rat function and it kinda worked. No nasty reports whilst booting. Yahoo ! :)