# many time consume to startup my pc on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer to start up my PC takes a lot of time, why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please give some more details like your hardware specs, perhaps?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix very slow Ubuntu booting?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35497/how-to-fix-very-slow-ubuntu-booting)

Answer (score 2):

This `systemd` command will sort services with their execution time.

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

You can then stop unwanted services by executing:

```
systemctl stop service_name
```

To disable it from starting on boot(startup) execute:

```
systemctl disable service_name
```

Comment: Good answer to a crap question...  Could you add how to disable services and drop me a comment and I'll come back and upvote!

Comment: @Fabby `systemctl stop $some_service` . To disable it from starting on boot : `systemctl disable $some_service`

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Fabby meant for you to add the info by [edit] into your answer. If you do, ping me as well.

Comment: @ElderGeek fixed, and my apologies to you. :)

Comment: You should be apologizing to @Fabby who did your work for you, not me. ;-)