# "Failed to send Message.", "Failed to send Previous Message."

Tags: boot, networking

I am writing asking about a very strange problem I have with my Ubuntu install. When booting, I noticed that it would take very long to get to the login screen where I could enter my password. After doing some searching, I found this article on AskUbuntu ([How to fix very slow Ubuntu booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35497/how-to-fix-very-slow-ubuntu-booting)) and the top solution was to try looking at the logs to solve the problem.

I looked at my logs, and much to my surprise there was something that definitely caught my eye...something that literally went on for the entire time while booting when I went to get a cup of coffee.

```
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX wpa_supplicant[884]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with **:**:**:**:**:** (SSID='***' freq=2452 MHz)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.714056] wlan0: authenticate with **:**:**:**:**:**
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX wpa_supplicant[884]: wlan0: Trying to associate with **:**:**:**:**:** (SSID='***' freq=2452 MHz)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.733923] wlan0: send auth to **:**:**:**:**:** (try 1/3)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.735464] wlan0: authenticated
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.737611] wlan0: associate with **:**:**:**:**:** (try 1/3)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.740969] wlan0: RX AssocResp from **:**:**:**:**:** (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=6)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.741356] wlan0: associated
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.741361] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX wpa_supplicant[884]: wlan0: Associated with **:**:**:**:**:**
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742919] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742920] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742921] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742923] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm), (N/A)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742924] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742925] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742926] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742927] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742927] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.742928] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX NetworkManager[868]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.768337] Failed to send Message.
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX wpa_supplicant[884]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with **:**:**:**:**:** [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX wpa_supplicant[884]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to **:**:**:**:**:** completed [id=0 id_str=]
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX wpa_supplicant[884]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with **:**:**:**:**:** (SSID='***' freq=2452 MHz)
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   19.944664] Failed to send Previous Message.
May 29 07:15:30 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [   20.119064] Failed to send Message.

[...]

May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully called chroot.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully dropped privileges.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully limited resources.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Running.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Watchdog thread running.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Canary thread running.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully made thread 1649 of process 1649 (n/a) owned by '112' high priority at nice level -11.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX colord: Device added: xrandr-Acer Technologies-S220HQL-LYKAA0018503
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX colord: Device added: xrandr-Acer Technologies-S220HQL-LYKAA0018505
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX colord: Automatic metadata add icc-cab9a8932f173aa809bb2cd93b757217 to xrandr-Acer Technologies-S220HQL-LYKAA0018505
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX colord: Profile added: icc-cab9a8932f173aa809bb2cd93b757217
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX colord: Automatic metadata add icc-294445fbd439cc2daf4a3ab159144ff1 to xrandr-Acer Technologies-S220HQL-LYKAA0018503
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX colord: Profile added: icc-294445fbd439cc2daf4a3ab159144ff1
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully made thread 1753 of process 1649 (n/a) owned by '112' RT at priority 5.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully made thread 1754 of process 1649 (n/a) owned by '112' RT at priority 5.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully made thread 1755 of process 1649 (n/a) owned by '112' RT at priority 5.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [  133.318287] usb 3-4: current rate 47872 is different from the runtime rate 48000
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [  133.319949] usb 3-4: current rate 47872 is different from the runtime rate 48000
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX pulseaudio[1649]: [pulseaudio] source.c: Default and alternate sample rates are the same.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [  133.330855] usb 3-4: current rate 47872 is different from the runtime rate 48000
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [  133.332505] usb 3-4: current rate 47872 is different from the runtime rate 48000
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully made thread 1756 of process 1649 (n/a) owned by '112' RT at priority 5.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Supervising 5 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully made thread 1757 of process 1649 (n/a) owned by '112' RT at priority 5.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Supervising 6 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully made thread 1758 of process 1649 (n/a) owned by '112' RT at priority 5.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Supervising 7 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Successfully made thread 1760 of process 1760 (n/a) owned by '112' high priority at nice level -11.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX rtkit-daemon[1651]: Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
May 29 07:17:24 ALBERT-LINUX pulseaudio[1760]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
May 29 07:21:45 ALBERT-LINUX anacron[1319]: Job `cron.daily' started
May 29 07:21:45 ALBERT-LINUX anacron[1774]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2017-05-29
May 29 07:25:14 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [  603.529461] Failed to send Previous Message.
May 29 07:25:15 ALBERT-LINUX kernel: [  603.703209] Failed to send Message.
```

I have bleeped out things like my network's SSID and MAC addresses, because those shouldn't really matter as far as I know.

I'm currently running an Intel Core i5-4440 on an MSi Z97 PC MATE with 8GB of Kingston HyperX DDR3-1600 memory o/c'd to 1866 MHz with a Gigabyte R9 380 G1 Gaming Edition and an Asus PCE-n15 Wi-Fi adapter.

Any support would be greatly appreciated!

~Al