# Slow startup on a Dell Inspiron 1012

Tags: boot, performance, shutdown

Ubuntu11.10 is very slow to start up and shutdown comparing with ubuntu 11.04. I am using ubuntu 11.10 on a mini Dell Inspiron 1012 (N450 atom)

I only have one program in the startup applications and my kernel is up to date. I don't have any old kernels in my boot list, so why does it take so much time between showing the dell logo and ubuntu logo?

- I also have this problem with GNOME Shell

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Can you edit your question to indicate whether this is an upgrade from 11.04 or a fresh install? I'm not an expert, but it might make a difference.

Comment: Can you run bootchart and edit it into your question? Look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/10507/235

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I improve boot speed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed)

Comment: @Ax3 post the output : ls -l /etc/xdg/autostart   "Is 11.10 is fresh installed or upgraded from 11.04?  What the program is that in startup list you mentioned ?  When ubuntus show 'ubuntu boot progress'(LOGO) press up key which will switch your mode to command line and you can see why your system is taking too much time ". Do the last things : sudo gedit /etc/default/grub  "change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset" then update the grub with the command  sudo update-grub

Answer (score 1):

My friend had the exact same issue using an Asus eee pad. He complained that after the update to 11.10 the loading time was massively increased. I suggested that he give Gnome 3 a try to see if it fairs any better. He reported that load times were back to being reasonable after the install.

Gnome 3 used to be a little tricky to setup, but I haven't tried in a while. You can try  out Gnome 3 with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Other than that I haven't seen any other solutions. There is talk however of a focus on increased boot times in Ubuntu 12.04. Hopefully, if the matter isn't too urgent and Gnome 3 doesn't work out for you, you can wait just a little longer (April 2012).

Comment: thank u  . i tried it but useless

Answer (score 1):

If you have an external CD/DVD drive, check to make sure you don't have any media in the CD/DVD tray.

This happened to me for 2 days and then I realized I had left a DVD in the tray.