# How to measure desktop login time with bootchart

Tags: 12.04, bootchart

I've got an issue whereby after each reboot the first time I log into my session it takes ages. That is, it can take up to five minutes from the moment I enter my password until I can use the desktop.

I was trying to use bootchart to debug the issue, but while bootchart itself worked, the graphics output are cropped at 105 seconds, so I cannot even see when compiz starts.

Looking at `/etc/init/bootchart.conf`, it seems the graphic is cropped indeed after compiz start, but it doesn't seem to be my case

```
bootchart --format=$format \
    --crop-after=compiz,metacity,mutter,kwin,xfwm4 \
    --annotate=ureadahead,mountall,hostname,hwclock \
    --annotate=Xorg \
    --annotate=gdm-session-worker \
    --output="/var/log/bootchart" "$TARBALL"
```

Here is some [example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLYOS.png).

Is there any way I can see a longer time axis on the graph, at least until the desktop is loaded?

Comment: Have you looked in dmesg or ~/.xsession-errors to see what errors or problems are occurring?

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.bootchart.org/docs.html) does not mention a hard limit of 105 seconds, only that 'The logger will try to detect the end of the boot process by looking for specific processes.' Examples are `gdmgreeter` or `kdm_greet`. Are you sure it is possible to get what you want with this program?

Comment: I haven't looked at dmesg, but I had a chat with the guys on the #ubuntu-desktop channel to try to debug it, couldn't see anything obvious on `~/.xsession-errors` http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1094584/

Comment: @TomBrossman, I don't know if it's possible, hence the question too.

Comment: You can use [pybootchartgui](http://code.google.com/p/pybootchartgui/) to programmatically access the bootchart data (not sure how useful that could be though). By the way, I see it's been integrated into a single project in [bootchart2](https://github.com/mmeeks/bootchart).

Comment: Looks like bootchart2 supports [customizing the exit condition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bootchart#Stop_Bootchartd2_after_login).

Comment: This will not answer your question, but may help find the problem. If you have any external HDD attached, or two or more HDD's inside your computer, one or more of these could be failing. I gained an extra 150 seconds when I removed an old Hard Disk from the system.

Comment: If you create a test user on the workstation, does it take the same amount of time to login?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `pybootchartgui` (available in Software Centre). It'd create a graphical log after each boot.
Checking `dmesg` output would be equally good, but less 'visual'.

Please disable from Startup Application whatever you don't need, and make sure that the HDD is the 1st boot device in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

The bootchart displays how much time a service takes while the system boots up

Zoom in the existing image
That's what I do

Images are stored in /var/log/bootchart folder

Answer (score -1):

Check /var/log/messages after you booted? It has a log with the times from during the boot sequence.

You might try running bootchart.

Check out this question also [How can I see what happens during the boot process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10503/how-can-i-see-what-happens-during-the-boot-process/10507#10507)

an alternative application to bootchart called pybootchartgui available in Ubuntu Software Center.

http://code.google.com/p/pybootchartgui/