# How can I debug what's slowing down new session logins?

Tags: 12.04

For a while, I've had an issue whereby it takes up to 5 minutes from the moment I enter my password in Lightdm's login screen until I can do anything with my computer. That's on Ubuntu 12.04.

During that time, I see there is disk activity, but I'm not sure how to figure out what's causing it and whether that is the real cause.

I've played around with [Bootchart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164187/how-to-measure-desktop-login-time-with-bootchart) unsuccessfully. Any ideas on what the best way to debug this issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what processes are accessing the disk run:

```
sudo iotop -o
```

To stop the output disappearing after each access and to make the disk I/O cumulative (more useful in my opinion) run:

```
sudo iotop -oa
```

Play with the options (`iotop -h`) as required.

As I recall `iotop` needs to be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install iotop.
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would try is to press Alt-Ctrl-F1 to switch to a text console, log in there and run `top` in the console. Then switch to the login screen again using Alt-Ctrl-F7, enter your login/password and while it tries to log you in switch back to the text console to see if you can spot any processes which cause the problem.